# How to find the mathematical expression for finding a missing number in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

In the missing number problem:

> Find the missing number in given integer array of 1 to 100?

Here is the code in python for this problem:

## n cannot be predefined as it depends on the array which is assigned in the function

```
def missingNumber(nums):
    n = len(nums)
    total = (n+1)*(n+2)/2
    missing = total - sum(nums)
    return missing

missingNumber([1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
```

I don't understand the logic of how to come up with

```
total = (n+1)*(n+2)/2
```

Comment: `(n+1)*(n+2)/2` is the mathematical formula for the sum of the numbers `1, 2, 3 ... (n-1), n, (n+1)`.

Comment: I assume you never heard of young Gauss method for summing numbers? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

Comment: Have you thought of bit manipulation using XOR? That formula is not the only way to solve it( just in case if that was tricky for you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given that, one number is missing in an array of consecutive numbers,

Lets assume that you know the sum of first n numbers. Let sum of first n numbers be s. Now that one number is missing from the first n numbers, we can get the missing number as

`s - sum of remaining numbers`

Now lets see how we can calculate s,

Lets say I have numbers "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....,100"

Now I want to calculate the sum of them,

One thing I can do is either feed it to a computer program / calculator or take sum one by one.

Other way which Young Gauss came up when asked this question by his teacher was,

`let s1 = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 100`

`take the reverse of it,`

`let s2 = 100 + 99 + 98 + ... + 1`

`Now add s1 and s2`

`s1 + s2 = (100 + 1) + (99 + 2) + .... + (1 + 100)`

`but s1 = s2, so,`

`2s1 = 101 + 101 + ...  + 101 // sequence has 100 terms`

`s1 = (101)*(100) / 2 // sum of first 100 numbers`

So we have, sum of first n numbers as `(n)*(n+1)/2` in a generalized way. This can also be proved by mathematical induction.

For your problem if n is the length of array with missing number, then n + 1 must be the original array size. so `s = (n+1)*(n+2)/2`

Answer (score 1):

You should not have n as an argument. It will raise the error.
    TypeError: missingNumber() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

and n is defined later in the function.

Also there is an error in the function .

For example if num = [1,2,3,4,5,6] the output will be 7
but your array is supposed to end at 6.

***The answer for your question :-***

(n + 1)*(n+2) / 2 is the sum of the first n+1 natural numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find a single missing number, here is the code,

```
def missingNumber(nums):
    n = nums[-1]
    total = (n)*(n+1)/2
    missing = total - sum(nums)
    return missing
```

If you are willing to find multiple missing numbers, then the below code could help,

```
def missingNumbers(nums):
    missingNumbers = []
    count = 0
    for n in range(nums[-1]):
        if n + 1 != nums[count]:
            missingNumbers.append(n + 1)
        else:
            count = count + 1
    return missingNumbers
```

Both the codes assume the input always start with one and increments in steps of one.